# Decrypting the YSOD, techniques to the mayhem

Tags: asp.net, debugging

How many can relate do this?

> ## Server Error in / Application
>
> ---
>
> ### *Object reference not set to an object*
>
> **Description:** Object reference not set to an object.
>
> **Exception Details:** `System.NullReferenceException`: Object reference not set to an object.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> ```
> Line 56:    posts.Add(post);
> ```

On a more serious note, what are the first things you look for when you see the
yellow screen of death? Half the time the debug trace isn't actually telling you what the problem is (understandable I guess).

I must admit, I still use `Response.Write` more than I should.  I just get lazy going through the debugger.  What techniques do you use to debug the problem?

Comment: one thing I do notice is that the problem is many times one level below the suggested level in the stack trace...

Comment: I think that the stack trace is, actually, relatively useful for non-system errors.  It's helped me narrow down issues pretty frequently.

Comment: Love your graphics! "Object reference not set to an object" is SO infuriating!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm unable to identify/resolve the issue using the error message that the page presents to me, I will typically try to use the Windows Event Viewer to help me identify what is causing the issue.

For example, SharePoint errors are sometimes far less than descriptive.  So, I'll combine what I'm seeing on the Y.S.O.D. with error messages from the Event Viewer to help me narrow down the cause.

I will do my best to ask a co-worker or other associate that I think might have some experience that might help.  If I'm still unable to identify the cause, I will resort to Google armed with all the information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I try to reduce the number of YSODs. One of the first things I do when starting work on an app is to create a custom exception class.

- Add properties such as the SQL
  statement being run. Two display
  message text fields, one for display
  to users, one for display to
  developers (in debug mode) Who is
  the logged-in user. Get all the form
  variables so you know what they were
  trying to enter.
- Log the errors somewhere (event log
  is good, if you can access the web
  server; logging to the database is
  less successful when so many
  exceptions are inability to access
  the database).
- Create code in the MasterPage or web page base class Page Error events and Application Error events to do the logging.
- Create a custom error page. When in
  debug mode, the custom error page
  displays everything. When not in
  debug mode (production), display
  only selected properties of the
  custom exception.

Investing the time up front to do this will save you many hours of anguish later.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do my debugging on my local machine with the Cassini web server (comes with VS 2005/2008).  If I see an exception on my QA or, heaven forbid, my production box it's usually because I forgot to update my connection strings so that they point to the QA/production database instead of my local machine.

In other cases, I've found the stack traces to be very helpful in determining where to provide breakpoints so I step through it in the debugger and examine the data at runtime.  The only time I've written any debugging information on the page was when trying to find some performance issues that I couldn't replicate on my developer instance.  In this case I wrote some hidden fields that contained timing information about various parts of the render process.

Answer (score 0):

the error info provided, assuming you are in debug mode, will give you information as to what line the error actually occurred on, along with the lines of code leading up to the error. This info should give you a good start on defining where to set your break points for debugging.

I was once in your shoes many moons ago, using response.write for debugging. Once you start using the IDE and debugger as it's intended you'll find yourself pulling out less hair and getting to the solutions much faster.

Also, opening up the immediate window while debugging is gonna make your life even more happy.

Comment: having a fast machine helps that's for sure ram ram ram!

Answer (score 0):

Use a decent logging framework such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html), and be liberal in your use of DEBUG-level logging.

It's essentially a neater version of your Response.Write approach, which can be left in your production code and "switched on" when required.

Comment: Sure, that's why you make sure it's possible to switch it on and off.
log4net is optimized for speed, and the FAQ gives examples of coding practices which will reduce the impact on your product speed when logging is disabled. http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html